# Prolog: simulate disjunctive facts

Tags: prolog, logic

I've got a logic problem that I'd like to solve, so I thought, "I know, I'll try Prolog!"

Unfortunately, I'm running into a brick wall almost immediately. One of the assumptions involved is a disjunctive fact; either A, B or C is true (or more than one), but I do not know which. I've since learned that this is [something Prolog does not support](http://faculty.nps.edu/ncrowe/book/chap14.html).

There's a lot of documentation out there that seems to address the subject, but most of it seems to immediately involve more intricate concepts and solves more advanced problems. What I'm looking for is an isolated way to simulate defining the above fact (as defining it straight away is, by limitations of Prolog, not possible).

How could I address this? Can I wrap it in a rule somehow?

**EDIT:** I realise I have not been very clear. Given my lack of familiarity with Prolog, I did not want to get caught up in a syntax error when trying to convey the problem, and instead went with natural language. I guess that did not work out, so I'll give it a shot in pseudo-Prolog anyway.

Intuitively, what I would want to do would be something like this, to declare that either `foo(a)`, `foo(b)` or `foo(c)` holds, but I do not know which:

```
foo(a); foo(b); foo(c).
```

Then I would expect the following result:

```
?- foo(a); foo(b); foo(c).
true
```

Unfortunately, the fact I'm trying to declare (namely `foo(x)` holds for at least one `x \in {a, b, c}`) cannot be defined as such. Specifically, it results in `No permission to modify static procedure '(;)/2'`.

Side-note: after declaring the disjunctive fact, the result of `?- foo(a).` would be a bit unclear to me from a logical perspective; it is clearly not `true`, but `false` does not cover it either -- Prolog simply does not have sufficient information to answer that query in this case.

**EDIT 2:** Here's more context to make it more of a real-world scenario, as I might have over-simplified and lost details in translation.

Say there are three people involved. Alice, Bob and Charlie. Bob holds two cards out of the set `{1, 2, 3, 4}`. Alice asks him questions, in response to which he shows her one card that Charlie does not see, or shows no cards. In case more cards are applicable, Bob shows just one of them. Charlie's task is to learn what cards Bob is holding. As one might expect, Charlie is an automated system.

Alice asks Bob "Do you have a 1 or a 2?", in response to which Bob shows Alice a card. Charlie now learns that Bob owns a 1 or a 2.

Alice then asks "Do you have a 2 or a 3", to which Bob has no cards to show. Clearly, Bob had a 1, which he showed Alice previously. Charlie should now be able to derive this, based on these two facts.

What I'm trying to model is the knowledge that Bob owns a 1 or a 2 (`own(Bob, 1) \/ own(Bob, 2)`), and that Bob does not own a 2 or a 3 (`not (own(Bob, 2) \/ own(Bob, 3))`). Querying if Bob owns a 1 should now be `true`; Charlie can derive this.

Comment: ask a specific question please. write some pseudocode, and give us an intended output (or operations).

Comment: you can declare this as `one_of_three(A):- memberchk(A,[a,b,c]).` rule.

Comment: Right. I feel like the confusion here is about whether I'm trying to _query_ if 'one of three holds' rather than _assume the knowledge_ that 'one of three holds', and query based on that.

Comment: @Joost as we've asked you several times now, sorry for having to repeat this, please *provide us with a specific sample query and its intended output*. don't worry about the syntax, just write it down, fully. with the rule defined as I suggested, the sample query would be `?- one_of_three(A).` result is `A=a` which is the same as `true`, logically. Or you could ask `?- A=c, one_of_three(A).`.

Comment: Or you could ask `?- _A=c, one_of_three(_A).` and it would return `true` as you wanted.

Comment: I assumed my last line was sufficiently specific, though. I want to query `?- own(Bob, 1).` to test if Bob has card 1, which should return `true`. Or am I still missing what you mean with 'specific query'?

Comment: @Joost I didn't see your edit2 for some reason. hmm.

Comment: either you use `assert/1` and friends, or you just hold the current state of your knowledge as a list of some atomic or compound data, that's all. and use of `assert` is frowned upon, so. You start with `Knowledge = knowledge( cards([1,2,3,4]), bob_holds_for_sure([]) )` or whatever, and process this `knowledge`, refining it as you learn new facts, checking them against the current knowledge to produce its updated version (or reject it as inconsistent), according to your game's rules. Sounds suspiciously similar to what Prolog does? Right, you can also write a mini-interpreter, to do this.

Comment: @Joost ... write a mini-interpreter in Prolog, of course.

Comment: For the sake of completeness I'll repeat my response on the answer here as well, since I feel like it's relevant to this aspect too. The solution does not necessarily need to be an interative program; adding new observations about Bob's cards could be added facts, populating the database differently from scratch rather than adding rules to modify a state.

Comment: The book you are referring to was released in 1988. The statement regarding higher-order predicate support in Prolog has since become obsolete (in 2012, to be precise).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The straight-forward answer to your question**:

if you can model your problem with constraint logic programming over finite domains, then, an "exclusive or" can be implemented using `#\` as follows:

> Of the three variables X, Y, Z, exactly one can be in the domain 1..3.

```
D = 1..3, X in D #\ Y in D #\ Z in D
```

To generalize this, you can write:

```
disj(D, V, V in D #\ Rest, Rest).

vars_domain_disj([V|Vs], D, Disj) :-
    foldl(disj(D), Vs, Disj, V in D #\ Disj).
```

and use it as:

```
?- vars_domain_disj([X,Y,Z], 2 \/ 4 \/ 42, D).
D = (Y in 2\/4\/42#\ (Z in 2\/4\/42#\ (X in 2\/4\/42#\D))).
```

If you don't use CLP(FD), for example you can't find a nice mapping between your problem and integers, you can do something else. Say your variables are in a list `List`, and any of them, but exactly one, can be `foo`, and the rest cannot be `foo`, you can say:

```
?- select(foo, [A,B,C], Rest), maplist(dif(foo), Rest).
A = foo,
Rest = [B, C],
dif(B, foo),
dif(C, foo) ;
B = foo,
Rest = [A, C],
dif(A, foo),
dif(C, foo) ;
C = foo,
Rest = [A, B],
dif(A, foo),
dif(B, foo) ;
false.
```

The query reads: in the list `[A,B,C]`, one of the variables can be `foo`, then the rest must be different from `foo`. You can see the three possible solutions to that query.

### Original answer

It is, sadly, often claimed that Prolog does not support one thing or another; usually, this is not true.

Your question is not exactly clear at the moment, but say you mean that, with this program:

```
foo(a).
foo(b).
foo(c).
```

You get the following answer to the query:

```
?- foo(X).
X = a ;
X = b ;
X = c.
```

Which you probably interpreted as:

> `foo(a)` is true, **and** `foo(b)` is true, **and** `foo(c)` is true.

But, if I understand your question, you want a rule which says, for example:

> **exactly one** of `foo(a)`, `foo(b)`, and `foo(c)` can be true.

However, depending on the context, that it, the rest of your program and your query, the original solution can mean exactly that!

But you really need to be more specific in your question, because the solution will depend on it.

### Edit after edited question

Here is a solution to that particular problem using constraint programming over finite domains with the great [`library(clpfd)` by Markus Triska](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpfd), available in SWI-Prolog.

Here is the full code:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

cards(Domain, Holds, QAs) :-
    all_distinct(Holds),
    Holds ins Domain,
    maplist(qa_constraint(Holds), QAs).

qa_constraint(Vs, D-no) :-
    maplist(not_in(D), Vs).
qa_constraint([V|Vs], D-yes) :-
    foldl(disj(D), Vs, Disj, V in D #\ Disj).

not_in(D, V) :- #\ V in D.

disj(D, V, V in D #\ Rest, Rest).
```

And two example queries:

```
?- cards(1..4, [X,Y], [1 \/ 2 - yes, 2 \/ 3 - no]), X #= 1.
X = 1,
Y = 4 ;
false.
```

> If the set of cards is {1,2,3,4}, and Bob is holding two cards, and when Alice asked "do you have 1 or 2" he said "yes", and when she asked "do you have 2 or 3" he said no, then: can Charlie know if Bob is holding a 1?

To which the answer is:

> Yes, and if Bob is holding a 1, the other card is 4; there are no further possible solutions.

Or:

```
?- cards(1..4, [X,Y], [1 \/ 2 - yes, 2 \/ 3 - no]), X #= 3.
false.
```

> Same as above, can Charlie know if Bob is holding a 3?
>
> Charlie knows for sure that Bob is not holding a three!

What does it all mean?

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

Makes the library available.

```
cards(Domain, Holds, QAs) :-
    all_distinct(Holds),
    Holds ins Domain,
    maplist(qa_constraint(Holds), QAs).
```

This defines the rule we can query from the top level. The first argument must be a valid domain: in your case, it will be `1..4` that states that cards are in the set {1,2,3,4}. The second argument is a list of variables, each representing one of the cards that Bob is holding. The last is a list of "questions" and "answers", each in the format `Domain-Answer`, so that `1\/2-yes` means "To the question, do you hold 1 or 2, the answer is 'yes'".

Then, we say that all cards that Bob holds are distinct, and each of them is one of the set, and then we map each of the question-answer pairs to the cards.

```
qa_constraint(Vs, D-no) :-
    maplist(not_in(D), Vs).
qa_constraint([V|Vs], D-yes) :-
    foldl(disj(D), Vs, Disj, V in D #\ Disj).
```

The "no" answer is easy: just say that for each of the cards Bob is holding, it is **not** in the provided domain: `#\ V in D`.

```
not_in(D, V) :- #\ V in D.
```

The "yes" answer means that we need an exclusive or for all cards Bob is holding; `2\/3-yes` should result in "Either the first card is 2 or 3, or the second card is 2 or 3, **but not both**!"

```
disj(D, V, V in D #\ Rest, Rest).
```

To understand the last one, try:

```
?- foldl(disj(2\/3), [A,B], Rest, C in 2\/3 #\ Rest).
Rest = (A in 2\/3#\ (B in 2\/3#\ (C in 2\/3#\Rest))).
```

Comment: I should have been clearer; it's not the rule that is a disjunction, but the fact that I'm trying to introduce. I've tried to illustrate with an example now.

Comment: Ah, I guess I'm still not clear enough, because ever which way I turn it, this is a different problem we're solving. I'll add more context.

Comment: @Joost this is the reason why SO guidelines ask the askers to ask *specific* questions. :) your initial intuition was incorrect (IMHO); you shouldn't represent your knowledge with Prolog database facts at all, as dynamic database programming is frowned upon, in Prolog.

Comment: Fair enough, that makes sense. I wouldn't mind making this a static, declarative thing, though, where adding new facts would mean adding to the code and re-running the entire program.. Does that still make it a dynamic database?

Comment: Right, that could be part of the query, but I thought it could be part of the declared database instead, (allow me to make use of the way Prolog resolves queries by itself, right?).. Why shouldn't it be?

Comment: @Joost It is better to leave as much as possible as part of the query; in this way, the solution is more general and can be used for different problems. See the updated answer!

Comment: Thanks! That clarified a whole lot. I wanted to make it part of the database for the sake of simplicity, but the code you presented is quite understandable for a novice as well. Out of curiousity: any insight on how it would work when not making it part of a query? Can I use the Q-A structure in that case as well?

Comment: @Joost Of course you can; maybe there is a clever way to do it, but you can easily make a list out of a table of facts, for example `bagof(Q-A, question_answer(Q, A), QAs)`

Answer (score 4):

A generate-and-test solution in vanilla Prolog:

```
 card(1). card(2). card(3). card(4).

 owns(bob, oneof, [1,2]).  % i.e., at least one of

 owns(bob, not, 2).

 owns(bob, not, 3).

 hand(bob, Hand) :-
   % bob has two distinct cards:
   card(X), card(Y), X < Y, Hand = [X, Y],
   % if there is a "oneof" constraint, check it:
   (owns(bob, oneof, S) -> (member(A,S), member(A, Hand)) ; true),
   % check all the "not" constraints:
   ((owns(bob, not, Card), member(Card,Hand)) -> false; true).
```

Transcript using the above:

```
$ swipl
['disjunctions.pl'].
% disjunctions.pl compiled 0.00 sec, 9 clauses
true.

?- hand(bob,Hand).
Hand = [1, 4] ;
;
false.
```

Note that Prolog is Turing complete, so generally speaking, when someone says "it can't be done in Prolog" they usually mean something like "it involves some extra work".

Comment: Great answer (+1). Can you expand the program so that it can also get to the "Bob also owns a 4"?

Comment: Now this is the kind of thing I was really looking for. Nice and clean, so that an absolute novice like myself can easily see what is going on. I'd like to see your thoughts on limiting Bob's hand to two cards from `{1,2,3,4}` to drive `owns(bob, 4)` as well, indeed!

Answer (score 2):

Just for the sake of it, here is a small program:

```
card(1). card(2). card(3). card(4). % and so on

holds_some_of([1,2]). % and so on

holds_none_of([2,3]). % and so on

holds_card(C) :-
    card(C),
    holds_none_of(Ns),
    \+ member(C, Ns).
```

I have omitted who owns what and such. I have not normalized `holds_some_of/1` and `holds_none_of/1` on purpose.

This is actually enough for the following queries:

```
?- holds_card(X).
X = 1 ;
X = 4.

?- holds_card(1).
true.

?- holds_card(2).
false.

?- holds_card(3).
false.

?- holds_card(4).
true.
```

which comes to show that you don't even need the knowledge that Bob is holding 1 or 2. By the way, while trying to code this, I noticed the following ambiguity, from the original problem statement:

> Alice asks Bob "Do you have a 1 or a 2?", in response to which Bob shows Alice a card. Charlie now learns that Bob owns a 1 or a 2.

Does that now mean that Bob has exactly **one** of 1 and 2, or that he could be holding **either one or both** of the cards?

### PS

The small program above can actually be reduced to the following query:

```
?- member(C, [1,2,3,4]), \+ member(C, [2,3]).
C = 1 ;
C = 4.
```

Comment: I intended for Bob to be holding 'either one or both'. I'll clear up the ambiguity in the question.

Comment: @Joost It is still the case that you don't need this information to deduce that Bob is holding 1 and 4. You don't even need to know that he is holding exactly two cards....

Comment: What do you mean with the statement that `holds_some_of/1` and `holds_none_of/1` are "not normalised"? Is this Prolog terminology, or generally in logic?

Comment: Hmm, you're right – I guess picking a toy example that correctly covers all properties in a minimal way is not trivial ;-)

Comment: @Joost I meant "normalized" as in a relational database. The Prolog database is somewhat like a relational database (not quite but I don't want to go into that discussion). So for example the [answer by @peak](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32471842/1812457) goes a bit further towards "normalizing" the table that holds the questions and answers.

Comment: @Joost If I had to summarize, the take home message would be: Prolog is a general purpose programming language, and whenever you read something along the lines of "_X_ is not possible due to the _Y_ limitation of Prolog", your BS detector should start beeping.

Answer (score 0):

(Eep, I just realized this is 6 years old, but maybe it's interesting to introduce logic-programming languages with probabilistic choices for the next stumbler )

I would say the accepted answer is the most correct, but if one is interested in probabilities, a PLP language such as problog might be interesting:

This example assumes we don't know how many cards bob holds.  It can be modified for a fixed number of cards without much difficulty.

```
card(C):- between(1,5,C). % wlog: A world with 5 cards

% Assumption: We don't know how many cards bob owns. Adapting to a fixed number of cards isn't hard either
0.5::own(bob, C):-
    card(C).
    
pos :- (own(bob,1); own(bob,2)).

neg :- (own(bob,2); own(bob,3)).

evidence(pos).   % tells problog pos is true.
evidence(\+neg). % tells problog neg is not true.

query(own(bob,Z)).
```

Try it online: https://dtai.cs.kuleuven.be/problog/editor.html#task=prob&hash=5f28ffe6d59cae0421bb58bc892a5eb1

Although the semantics of problog are a bit harder to pick-up than prolog, I find this approach an interesting way of expressing the problem. The computation is also harder, but that's not necessarily something the user has to worry about.